# How to generate a 2D array (with commas inside) from a graph

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I tried to generate 2 dimensional array from a graph (using NetworkX) and I used: `T = nx.attr_matrix(G,dtype=int, edge_attr=...)`
actually there are many ways to do that, but the given array is without commas like this:

```
    `[[ 0 18 11  0  0  0  0  0]
     [ 0  0  0 28  0  0  0  0]
     [ 0  0  0  0 14  0  0  0]
     [ 0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0]
     [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 20 14]
     [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
     [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
     [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]`
```

and I want it like this way:

```
    `[[ 0, 18, 11,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0, 28  ,0,  0  ,0,  0],
     [ 0 , 0 , 0,  0 ,14 , 0  ,0 , 0],
     [ 0  ,0 , 0,  0 , 0, 12  ,0  ,0],
     [ 0,  0 , 0,  0 , 0 , 0 ,20 ,14],
     [ 0 , 0 , 0,  0 , 0  ,0  ,0  ,0],
     [ 0  ,0 , 0,  0 , 0  ,0 , 0  ,0],
     [ 0  ,0 , 0,  0,  0  ,0,  0  ,0]]`
```

more over, I can't access to the elements (in the first array) by: T[1][2] for example

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to convert a string to an array? e.g. `numpy.mat(s).reshape(8,8)`, where `s` is the string above (matrix w/o commas)

Comment: Thank you bubble but it doen't work. What I'm looking for exactly is to access an array's elements by varying "i" and "j" (rows and columns) by: array[i][j] (as in C++ and Java)